# IllegalArgumentException: Bound must be positive

Tags: java, random, bukkit, illegalargumentexception

I get an error saying that my bound must be positive.
Here is the line I get it on:

```
inv.setItem(i, items.get(r.nextInt(items.size())));
```

As far as I know, it comes from the part where I request a random integer from the list of items.
This is how I defined the list:

```
List<ItemStack> items = getAllItems(level);
```

Where the `getAllItems()` method looks like:

```
public List<ItemStack> getAllItems(int level) {
    List<ItemStack> items = new ArrayList<ItemStack>();
    for (String item : settings.getChests().getStringList("chestitems." + level)) {
        ItemStack toAdd = parseItem(item);
        items.add(toAdd);
    }
    return items;
}
```

I get this stacktrace:

```
[19:03:53 ERROR]: Error occurred while enabling KitPvP v0.5 (Is it up to date?)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bound must be positive
        at java.util.Random.nextInt(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_51]
        at me.iamguus.gamegetsiepunt.kitpvp.chests.ChestsUtil.randomlyFillInv(ChestsUtil.java:101) ~[?:?]
        at me.iamguus.gamegetsiepunt.kitpvp.Main.onEnable(Main.java:40) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:321) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-5818108-a486600]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:335) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-5818108-a486600]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:405) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-5818108-a486600]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.loadPlugin(CraftServer.java:356) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-5818108-a486600]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:316) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-5818108-a486600]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.reload(CraftServer.java:746) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-5818108-a486600]
        at org.bukkit.Bukkit.reload(Bukkit.java:534) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-5818108-a486600]
        at org.bukkit.command.defaults.ReloadCommand.execute(ReloadCommand.java:25) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-5818108-a486600]
        at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:141) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-5818108-a486600]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:646) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-5818108-a486600]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.dispatchServerCommand(CraftServer.java:632) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-5818108-a486600]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.DedicatedServer.aO(DedicatedServer.java:405) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-5818108-a486600]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.DedicatedServer.B(DedicatedServer.java:369) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-5818108-a486600]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.A(MinecraftServer.java:657) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-5818108-a486600]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:560) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-5818108-a486600]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_51]
```

Comment: Well ... obviously you have an empty items list, so that `items.size()` evaluates to 0. And this is not allowed as a bound for `Random.nextInt(int)`.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose It may not be obvious to everyone! But this is the case, `getAllItems()` is returning an empty list of items.

Comment: Ok, so at the 'getAllItems()' method, i changed '"chestitems." + level' to '"chestitems.1"'. Now the system does work. I still don't understand it although I know this method is returning null.

Comment: Ok, so I was being dumb again. I rechecked the list and found out that something was 0. Changed it and it worked like a charm. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 24):

The issue is that you are calling `Random.nextInt()` with a zero and it doesn't like that. That is happening because the `List` from `getAllItems()` is empty. I would prevent this situation by checking that the list has items before performing your logic:

```
List<ItemStack> items = getAllItems(level);
if(!items.isEmpty()) {
    inv.setItem(i, items.get(r.nextInt(items.size())));
}
```

Answer (score 6):

As your stack trace says,

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bound must be positive
> at java.util.Random.nextInt(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_51]

The argument to `nextInt()` needs to be a positive integer. You will need to find out where you're passing a non-positive input to that method.