# Java IllegalArgumentException: bound must be positive

Tags: java

Here is my part of code, which throws exception:

```
List<Car> car1store = new ArrayList<>();

//adding any number of cars to car1store

Random rnd = new Random();
double randNumber = rnd.nextDouble();

if (randNumber < 0.25) {
    int attempt = rnd.nextInt(car1store.size()); 
    Car car = car1store.get(attempt);
}
```

I have already searched for why does this exception appear, but I seriously can't find how car1store.size() can be a negative number. The least number it can be is only a zero. Can you see my mistake?

Comment: First off, I would make car1store an ArrayList rathing than relying on polymorphism. After you change that could you please send the exact line the error occurs on? Thanks!!!

Comment: Zero is not positive. It also isn't negative, but it's not positive. The argument for `nextInt()` is an exclusive upper bound, so it has to be greater than 0 - after all, it makes no sense to ask for "a number >= 0, but also < 0"

Comment: @PatrickOshea yes, just appeared again. Did several attempts and it's here again.

Comment: `int attempt` also can be negative because of `rnd`. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32101688/illegalargumentexception-bound-must-be-positive)

Comment: This line: int attempt = rnd.nextInt(car1store.size());

Comment: @Kalana From the docs - _Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive), drawn from this random number generator's sequence._ How can it return a negative?

Comment: Show us how you are adding a car to `car1store`

Answer (score 1):

> Bound must be positive

The error message clearly states the issue here. The size of your `ArrayList` is `0`. It is not positive.

The bigger problem here is that you are trying to `.get()` from an empty list.

You should be adding some elements to the list and then try to access it.

Comment: His code code comments say that he's adding cars.That's not his issue.

Comment: @neildo He has only commented, not added any elements to the list.

Answer (score 1):

You faced this problem because `car1store.size()` is `0` and `rnd.nextInt` requires a bound greater than `0`. You can understand the problem with the following code:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        System.out.println(rand.nextInt(0));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bound must be positive
    at java.base/java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:388)
    at Main.main(Main.java:6)
```